# What is this for loop doing C++ ? tempList[j+1]

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, for-loop

I know the output and it is printing correctly: `49 49 46 40 31 19 4` but how is it getting there through this equation tempList[j+1] + j * num? From my understanding if I took away  `+ j * num` the result would be `1010101`. But adding the `j+1` in brackets makes it `444444`. So how does `j*num` become that final result?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int *tempList;
    int num = 3; 

    tempList = new int[7];
    tempList[6] = 4;

    for (int j = 5; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        tempList[j] = tempList[j+1] + j * num; 
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
    {
        cout << tempList [j] << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;
 }
```

Comment: *So how does `j*num` become that final result?* -- Because the program is doing exactly what it is told to do?

Comment: It is, but my question is how is it getting there? This equation is confusing me: tempList[j+1] + j * num

Comment: Why not trace it by hand, or better yet, follow it using a debugger?  There is no magic that the program is doing.

Comment: i tried and even took it apart as mentioned above. Can you show me an example

Comment: Take out a piece of paper.  Draw with boxes the `tempList` array.  Have a column of `j` values.  Run through that loop, step by step, erasing and replacing the boxes the values that are produced, and decrementing the `j` value.  If you can't do that, then I don't know what else to tell you, since it is the basis of programming -- being able to do a run-through by hand.

Comment: The first round in the loop you have `j = 5`, so the code is `tempList[5] = tempList[6] + 5 * num;`, and `tempList[6]` and `num` have values given in the lines just before. So now you know `tempList[5]`. Then just repeat.

Comment: Thanks, Bo Persson!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no strange thing.

```
num=3
tempList[6]=4

j=5, num=3
tempList[5] = tempList[6]+ j*num
tempList[5]=4 + (5*3) = 19

j=4, num=3
tempList[4] = tempList[5]+ j*num
tempList[4]=19 + (4*3) = 31

j=3, num=3
tempList[3] = tempList[4]+ j*num
tempList[3]=31 + (3*3) = 40

j=2, num=3
tempList[2] = tempList[3]+ j*num
tempList[2]=40 + (2*3) = 46 

j=1, num=3
tempList[1] = tempList[2]+ j*num
tempList[1]=46 + (1*3) = 49

j=0, num=3
tempList[0] = tempList[1]+ j*num
tempList[0]=49 + (0*3) = 49
```